# jQuery not always loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, menu, loading

I've always had this problem on this particular site, however it's starting to effect the overall experience. jQuery isn't always working properly. For example I have a page with a custom drop down that uses Jquery. Most of the time it loads however 10% of the time you click on the button and the div doesn't show. I really don't know what's happening with my site.

Comment: Sounds like the window ready isn't loading, if you're using the $(function() { .. }); syntax. Use chrome's network inspector to see if any resources are stopping the page from loading completely, like a javascript file hosted on another domain

Comment: wouldn't make a difference if I'm useing $(document).ready(function(){...});?

Comment: The way you pointed out is the longhand way of what I said, they both do the same thing. The important thing you need to find is whether or not you're waiting for an external resource before your javascript is allowed to fire. Do you have an example URL?

Comment: No, everything is under construction so only my ip has access. I would I find this out?

Comment: Use chrome/firefox code inspector. See if jQuery is loaded. And where it is loaded! (not at the bottom of page or after other plugins)

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking to jquery on Google's CDN? If not you, you should be [See here as to why.](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/)

Google's CDN is almost always up, but it is still good practice to always have a backup local copy of jquery as well. This snippet first links out to google's CDN version. If for whatever reason it fails, it will load your local copy. This should fix any possibility of jquery not loading.

As mentioned above, you should also make sure that you're not initiating your custom dropdown until the document is ready.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (!window.jQuery) {
    document.write('<script src="/path/to/your/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#yourDropdown').customDropdown();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have a question, I include files via php, and the files I include also have a <script src="..."> could that be why it sometimes doesn't work?

Comment: It's really hard to debug this without seeing the source code. If you could even copy the page source from your local development page, that would help. One reason why it only works sometimes, is if your page includes different widgets that may be including an older version of jquery. This would override the whatever version was previously included (so if your dropdown script required jquery 1.6 but an older widget was including jquery 1.4, this would break it). Again, hard to debug without seeing any source code.